# Custom Recursive function |returning no values at all| in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I thought of making this An=8(An-1)*(An-1)/An-2 while a1=1,a0=1
With the following code for n=2 a2=0.0000 which is altogether wrong
On the other hand (Sum of An) S(n)=1+1+0.0000(false number) theoretically  correct

```
#include <stdio.h>
float rec(int n);
float sum(int n);
main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nInput N of term an: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

printf("\n\na%d=%f",n,rec(n));
printf("\n\nS(%d)=%f",n,sum(n));

}

float rec(int n)
{
    int i;
    float a[1000]={1,1};//a0=1,a1=1
    if(n<0)
        printf("\nNegative values of N are invalid");
    else if(n==0)
        return a[0];
    else if(n==1)
        return a[1];
    else if(n>1)
        for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
            a[i]=((8 * a[i-1]*a[i-1]) - 1)/a[i-2];
    return a[i];
}

float sum(int n)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        sum+=rec(i);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I'm obviously missing something.  Where is the recursion here?

Comment: Mathematical recursion, terribly sorry wrong tag

Comment: Why static ? its still in local range right?

Comment: AH, got it.  Probably my fault.  The brain sometimes sees (or doesn't) what it expects.

Comment: change `return a[i];` to `return a[n];`.

Comment: Duck i used wrong tag Recursion is not for mathematics section

Comment: BLUEPIXY a[i]=a[n] at the end of the loop , its not like **i** is automatically discarded right after the loop right?

Comment: You realize that every time you call `rec` you're recomputing 998 elements of your array.

Comment: And what do you mean, “returning no values at all”? It does return values, they just happen to be zero, a perfectly fine floating-point value.

Comment: @niCk i != n, Termination condition of the loop is `i <= n`, so turned `n + 1` after the loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY; That's `i+1`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY; Termination condition of the loop is `i <= n`, **so turned `i + 1` after the loop**.

Comment: @haccks What it would `i+1`? what ? i ? n ? when i = 3, i + 1 = 4? meaningless.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY; Yes. He is incrementing `i` to control the loop not `n`.

Comment: @haccks final value of `i` is `i ← n + 1`. it say   `i + 1`(`i ← i + 1`)  wrong(meaningless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float a[1000]={1,1};
```

initializes `a[0] = 1` and `a[1] = 1` and **rest of the elements to `0`**.

Now, you are returning `a[i]` from your function. For `n=2` it will return `a[3]`, which is `0` of course, but not the `a[2]` as you are expecting.

Now just change the return value to `a[i-1]` and it will work.

```
float rec(int n)
{
    int i;
    ...
    ...

    return a[i-1];
}
```

Comment: i think thats the point they will be filled later with for(i=2;

Comment: The program works perfect now!!! but I need to get this i=2 enters loop because i<=n does a[i=2] at the end it increments and falls out right?

Comment: For `i=2` loop executed because it met the condition `i<=n`, i.e, `n=2` which is equal to `i`. On second iteration it increments `i` first and then check for the condition `i<=n` which is `false` and loop is exited but `i` becomes `3` now.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
        a[i]=((8 * a[i-1]*a[i-1]) - 1)/a[i-2];
return a[i];
```

problem here, you will always get zero!!! why?

say i input 3,, now say i = 3,alls well a[3] gets calcualted, now you program goes back to the for loop, now i =4, it now does not fit the check i<=n, and so now i is 4,

you are returning a[i] which is actually a[myanswer+1]...

fix it by returning a[i-1]

Answer (score 1):

At this point in `rec`:

```
return a[i];
```

`i` is 3, not 2, because it was incremented before the last test of the loop.  As such you're returning the element of the array *after* the last one set.  Be careful if you fix this by returning `a[i-1]` because if `i` is never initialized or is 0, this will cause a problem.  You should clean up the `rec` method a bit to handle these corner cases, but the immediate problem is that `i` is 3, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
return a[i];
```

with

```
return a[n];
```

(As an aside, you do not need the extra branches for 0 and 1.)

Answer (score 1):

A beautiful example of [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) :)

- About half the computations are done unnecessarily multiple times
- The array is unnecessary and defeats the whole point of using a recursive approach

Beside, it is defined to hold 1000 values, but the function grows so fast that it will exceed a float capacity after 10 terms or so.

A more streamlined version [here](http://ideone.com/Bpdpyi) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

float A (int n, float * sum)
{
    if (n <= 0) { *sum = 0; return 0; }
    if (n == 1) { *sum = 1; return 1; }
    if (n == 2) { *sum = 2; return 1; }
    float anm2 = A(n-2, sum); // store A(n-2). sum will be overwritten by A(n-1)
    float anm1 = A(n-1, sum); // store A(n-1) once to avoid calling A twice, and get preceding sum
    float an = ((8 * anm1*anm1) - 1)/anm2;
    *sum += an;
printf ("index %d : term %g sum %g\n", n, an, *sum);
    return an;
}

int main (void)
{
    int n;
    float sum;
    printf("\nInput N of term an: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); printf("\n");

    printf("\na%d=%f",n,A(n, &sum));
    printf("\n\nS(%d)=%f",n,sum);
}
```

Beside, recursion is unnecessary and leads to inefficient and confusing code.

See a more straightforward solution [here](http://ideone.com/la2Vhf):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    float term;
    float sum;
} A; // current term and sum of series A

void compute_A (int n, A * res)
{
    int i;
    float anm1, // a[n-1]
          anm2; // a[n-2]

    // special case for n<=1
    if (n == 1)
    {
        res->sum = res->term = 1;
        return;
    }
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        res->sum = res->term = 0;
        return;
    }

    // initial terms
    anm2 = anm1 = 1;

    // initial sum
    float sum = anm1+anm2;

    // compute the remaining n-2 terms and cumulate the sum
    for (i = 2 ; i <= n ; i++)
    {
        // curent term
        float an = ((8 * anm1*anm1) - 1)/anm2;

        // cumulate sum
        sum += an;

        // shift computation window
        anm2 = anm1;
        anm1 = an;
printf ("index %d : term %g sum %g\n", i, an, sum);
    }

    // report result
    res->sum  = sum;
    res->term = anm1;
}

int main (void)
{
    int n;
    A res;
    printf("\nInput N of term an: ");
    scanf("%d",&n); printf("\n");

    compute_A (n, &res);

    printf("\na%d=%f",n,res.term);
    printf("\n\nS(%d)=%f",n,res.sum);
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use anything but static arrays for this exercise, and i don't think my program is inefficient as the aforementioned algorithm.Besides that if you took the time to actually read it you would realize that 10 terms are being held in 10 cells (No matter how big the number is) and are not enough to crash it

Comment: Don't take it personally. I am not paid to do this, you know... the `for(i=2;i<=n;i++)` loop is uselessly recomputing the whole set of values. You could sipmly compute the last term.

Comment: Recursion is inefficient because it creates a whole stack frame to perform the recursive call while a linear approach simply shifts the necessary variables to perform the next computation step. This exercise is a good illustration of how the seductive recursive approach can lead to complex and obfuscated code as soon as you stray from trivial examples. Now if you are going to use an array, there is no point in filling it recursively. your `for(i=2;i<=n;i++)` loop could be moved to a linear algorithm and do the job more effectively. But yet again, better get rid of the array altogether.

Comment: You are right about this one. But I am not running the program constantly , its a run-calculate-exit program so for(i=2;i<=n;i++) is not that false approach

Comment: Here again I am not here to belittle your efforts nor prove you wrong at all cost. I am just offering alternatives and pointing out possible ways of improvement. Arrays in C are cumbersome heavy beasts, that's why I think a solution that avoids using them is generally better. Recursion is full of traps and often leads to inefficiency, despite its apparent simplicty and aesthetic appeal. I think this exercise is a good opportunity to ponder about that. All this being said, the ultimate choice of how you will implement the solution is yours.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44253/discussion-between-kuroi-neko-and-nick)

Answer (score 0):

```
float rec(int n){
    static max_i = 1;
    static float a[1000]={1,1};//a0=1,a1=1
    int i;
    if(n<0){
        printf("\nNegative values of N are invalid");
        return NAN;//<math.h>
    }
    if(n >= 1000){
        printf("\nMore than 1000 are invalid");
        return NAN;
    }
    if(n<2)
        return a[n];
    if(n>max_i){
        for(i=max_i+1;i<=n;++i)
            a[i]=((8 * a[i-1]*a[i-1]) - 1)/a[i-2];
        max_i = n;
        return a[n];
    }
    return a[n];
}
```